# Hardware accelerated Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) Linux application on DE1-SoC using ARM processor (HPS)

Tags: c, linux, verilog, mmap, soc

I have created a Verilog file for the ALU which have the following operation: add, subtract, AND and reset. I then wrapped the ALU with Avalon memory slave interface so that the ARM processor can access it specifically via H2F lightweight bridge. Then after mmap() is done, the user can choose the operation and enter value for data1 and data2. The result will be displayed on the terminal. The offsets for each registers in ALU is 4 bit. Meaning that the base address of the registers in ALU had a 4bit span.

The problem I faced is I cant seem to write value into the ALU register (opcode,data1,data2). I have done the correct mapping using mmap() function. However, the result I get is always 0.

The ALU verilog code is shown in below.

```
module alu_avalon(
input clk,
input[1:0] opcode,
input[31:0] dataA,
input[31:0] dataB,
output[31:0] alu_result
);


assign alu_result =     (opcode == 0) ? 0               :
                        (opcode == 1) ? dataA + dataB   :
                        (opcode == 2) ? dataA - dataB   :
                                        dataA & dataB;

endmodule
```

The ALU is then wrapped with Avalon Memory Mapped slave interface as shown in the verilog coding below.

```
module alu_avalon_top (
input reset,
input clk,
input chipselect,
input [1:0]address,
input write,
input [31:0]writedata,
output [31:0]readdata
);

wire [31:0]lineA;
wire [31:0]lineB;
wire [1:0]opcode;
wire [31:0]result_alu;

alu_avalon inst3 (
                    .clk(clk),
                    .opcode(opcode),
                    .dataA(lineA),
                    .dataB(lineB),
                    .alu_result(result_alu)
                    );

alu_interface inst2(

                    .clk        (clk),
                    .reset      (reset),
                    .chipselect (chipselect),
                    .address    (address),
                    .writedata  (writedata),
                    .readdata   (readdata),
                    .alu_result (result_alu),
                    .data1      (lineA),
                    .data2      (lineB),
                    .opcode     (opcode),
                    .write      (write)
                    );


endmodule

module alu_interface (
input reset,
input clk,
input chipselect,
input [1:0]address,
input write,
input [31:0]writedata,
output reg [31:0]readdata,
output reg[1:0]opcode,
output reg[31:0]data1,
output reg[31:0]data2,
input[31:0] alu_result

);

always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

    if (reset == 0)
    begin
        readdata <= 0;
        data1 <= 0;
        data2 <= 0;
    end
    else 
    begin
        if(chipselect == 1 && write == 1)
        begin
            case (address)
                2'b00:      opcode <= writedata[1:0];
                2'b01:      data1 <= writedata;
                2'b10:      data2 <= writedata;
                default:    readdata <= alu_result;
            endcase
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

I have added the custom IP using Qsys and connect the avalon slave to the H2F lightweight bridge AXI master.

Qsys interconnect:
[Qsys interconnect map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcKsS.png)

The C coding for Linux application

```
#define HW_REGS_BASE ( ALT_LWFPGASLVS_OFST )
#define HW_REGS_SPAN ( 0x00200000 )
#define HW_REGS_MASK ( HW_REGS_SPAN - 1 )

volatile unsigned long *aluMap = NULL;
void *virtual_base;
int main(void){

    int fd;
    printf("Open memory map\n");
    if( ( fd = open( "/dev/mem", ( O_RDWR | O_SYNC ) ) ) == -1 ) {
        printf( "ERROR: could not open \"/dev/mem\"...\n" );
        return( 1 );
    }

    virtual_base = mmap( NULL, HW_REGS_SPAN , ( PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE ), MAP_SHARED, fd, HW_REGS_BASE );

    if( virtual_base == MAP_FAILED ) {
        printf( "ERROR: mmap() failed...\n" );
        close( fd );
        return( 1 );
    }
    aluMap = (unsigned char *)(virtual_base + ALU8_0_BASE);
    printf("ALU addr: %x\n", aluMap);
    volatile unsigned int *opcode =(unsigned int*)(aluMap + 0x0);
    volatile unsigned int *data1 = (unsigned int*)(aluMap + 0x4);
    volatile unsigned int *data2 = (unsigned int*)(aluMap + 0x8);
    volatile unsigned int *result= (unsigned int*)(aluMap + 0xc);
    printf("op:%x\ndat1:%x\ndat2:%x\nresult:%x\n", opcode,data1,data2,result);
    int op;
    int dat1;
    int dat2;
    printf("operation code: ");
    scanf(" %d", &op);
    *opcode = op;
    printf("data1: ");
    scanf(" %d", &dat1);
    *data1 = dat1;
    printf("data2: ");
    scanf(" %d", &dat2);
    *data2 = dat2;
    int z = *result;
    printf("The result is %d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is [ALU output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ6Bt.png)

Can someone shows me what have i done wrong in the coding or the connection? Have been troubleshooting this for a month... Is the memory mapping for the IP's registers different with IP that doesn't have register... Or do I need to write a ALU kernel driver so that the Linux can recognize the hardware ALU?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why not start with something simpler, like a single register whose value increments at each clock cycle, and try and read that? Currently, you have too many places where the error could lurk. By working with a simpler case first, you can limit the possible errors to a much smaller set.

Comment: As stated before, theres alot that could be going wrong. However, one thing I see is that you are only setting `readdata` in your Avalon slave interface when `write` is asserted, which it should be output when `write` is not asserted but `chipselect` is. `chipselect` is also depracated so unless this is an old version of qsys, you should use `read` instead for read transactions and keep `write` for write transactions.

Comment: @NominalAnimal yea I should start from something really simple. I just thought simple ALU is simple enough for me as a beginner to experiment on it. It turns out that I was so wrong. However, thanks to Unn who pointed out that chipselect is depracated in newer QSYS, I eventually succeeded in implementing ALU on DE1SoC! Will post the answer later. Thanks for the adive!

Comment: @Unn Thanks again for your inputs. After I had changed the chipselect, read and write signal, the ALU finally return valid result instead of 0. Will post the answer later. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to the online community for helping me to solve my problem.

As @Unn had pointed out,

> - Write signal should be used only for write transaction
> - Read signal should be used only for read transaction
> - chipselect is deprecated in newer QSYS

I have edited the verilog coding (separate read & write transaction and remove chipselect) and voila the ALU works like a charm.

```
always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

    if (reset == 0)
    begin
        readdata <= 0;
        data1 <= 0;
        data2 <= 0;
    end
    else 
    begin
        if(write == 1)
        begin
            case (address)
                2'b00:  opcode <= writedata[1:0];
                /* OPCODE
                 1: ADD
                 2: SUB
                 3: AND   */
                2'b01:  data1 <= writedata;
                2'b10:  data2 <= writedata;
                default:    ;
            endcase
        end
        else if (read == 1)
        begin
            case (address)
                2'b00:  readdata <= opcode;
                2'b01:  readdata <= data1;
                2'b10:  readdata <= data2;
                2'b11:  readdata <= alu_result;
                default: readdata <= 0;
            endcase
        end
    end
end
```

One more changes had to be done is to replace `#define HW_REGS_BASE ( ALT_LWFPGASLVS_OFST )` with `#define HW_REGS_BASE ( ALT_STM_OFST )` in the main.c program

Below is the ALU output terminal

[ALU output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfMwD.png)

Special thanks to [Rocketboard](https://forum.rocketboards.org/t/hardware-accelerated-arithmetic-logic-unit-alu-linux-application-on-de1-soc-using-arm-processor-hps/1726) community as well